# How to redirect to home page after registration?

Tags: redirect, user-registration, homepage, wp-redirect

I am using wordpress 4.6.

I have template register form with page URL `domain-name/account/?action=register`

I want to redirect it to home page after register but instead of that it show

message "You have logged in. You better go to Home" with page URL

```
domain-name/account/?result=registered.
```

I already try below code in theme functions.php

```
function __my_registration_redirect(){
    wp_redirect( '/my-account' );
    exit;
}
add_filter( 'registration_redirect', '__my_registration_redirect' );
```

but nothing happens

Answer (score 2):

Instead of your code why don't you try which in the [codex example](https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Filter_Reference/registration_redirect).

This simple example will redirect a user to the `home_url()` upon successful registration.

```
add_filter( 'registration_redirect', 'my_redirect_home' );
function my_redirect_home( $registration_redirect ) {
    return home_url();
}
```

Comment: Not working for me.

Comment: Do you using bbPress plugin? Please try this with after disable all plugins. Seems like there is a conflict with the plugin.

Comment: Yes I am using bbPress plugin.

Comment: There is a comfict with bbpress plugin and registration_redirect filter. You can try this code after disble the plugin. If you need to use bbpress ask your question on bbpress forum. Clearly mention the conflict.

Comment: Sorry but after deactivating bbpress plugin same problem is there.May it template level handing?

Comment: It is working on my side. Try the code with default WordPress theme (like twenty sixteen theme) without any plugin.

Comment: I have issue in theme registration form not in default wordpress registration. on my side default working fine.

Answer (score 0):

you can try this code below for log in and log out redirects

```
//  --  LOGIN | LOGOUT STUFF  -- functions.php
//add_filter('user_register', 'login_redirect'); 
add_filter('wp_login', 'login_redirect');
function login_redirect($redirect_to) {
    wp_redirect( home_url() );
    exit();
}

add_action('wp_logout','logout_redirect');
function logout_redirect(){
    wp_redirect( home_url() );
    exit();
}
/* END */
```